# How to force Sequential Javascript Execution?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, execution, synchronous

I've only found rather complicated answers involving classes, event handlers and callbacks (which seem to me to be a somewhat sledgehammer approach). I think callbacks may be useful but I cant seem to apply these in the simplest context. See this example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function myfunction()  {
        longfunctionfirst();
        shortfunctionsecond();
      }

      function longfunctionfirst() {
        setTimeout('alert("first function finished");',3000);
      }

      function shortfunctionsecond() {
        setTimeout('alert("second function finished");',200);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:myfunction();return false;">Call my function</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this, the second function completes before the first function; what is the simplest way (or is there one?) to force the second function to delay execution until the first function is complete?

---Edit---

So that was a rubbish example but thanks to David Hedlund I see with this new example that it is indeed synchronous (along with crashing my browser in the test process!):

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction() {
    longfunctionfirst();
    shortfunctionsecond();
}

function longfunctionfirst() {
    var j = 10000;
    for (var i=0; i<j; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += i;
    }
    alert("first function finished");
}

function shortfunctionsecond() {
    var j = 10;
    for (var i=0; i<j; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += i;
    }
    alert("second function finished");
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:myfunction();return false;">Call my function</a>
</body>
</html>
```

As my ACTUAL issue was with jQuery and IE I will have to post a separate question about that if I can't get anywhere myself!

Comment: Hope this will helpful https://github.com/dineshkani24/queuecall

Comment: Well I am glad its just not me who is struggling with this. I started to use nodejs for the processing of logs files. Everything about that processing dictates sequential operation, but I have spent so much time trying to force the required sequenes. I find with promises and all of the chaining of "then this" "then that" that we end up with unreadable code.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Well, `setTimeout`, per its definition, will not hold up the thread. This is desirable, because if it did, it'd freeze the entire UI for the time it was waiting. if you really need to use `setTimeout`, then you should be using callback functions:

```
function myfunction() {
    longfunctionfirst(shortfunctionsecond);
}

function longfunctionfirst(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('first function finished');
        if(typeof callback == 'function')
            callback();
    }, 3000);
};

function shortfunctionsecond() {
    setTimeout('alert("second function finished");', 200);
};
```

If you are *not* using `setTimeout`, but are just having functions that execute for very long, and were using `setTimeout` to simulate that, then your functions *would* actually be synchronous, and you would not have this problem at all. It should be noted, though, that AJAX requests are asynchronous, and will, just as `setTimeout`, not hold up the UI thread until it has finished. With AJAX, as with `setTimeout`, you'll have to work with callbacks.

Comment: Also, I should note that AJAX requests are *generally* asynchronous, but can be made to be synchronous.

Comment: @Justin: yes, that's a valid point, thanks for the remark. if the real case scenario of issue is indeed ajax-related, synchronous callbacks could be the solution

Comment: (altho the async-with-callback approach probably still gives greater control and readability of the execution flow)

Comment: He didn't ask for AJAX in the question

Comment: @Chris: you're right about that, i only briefly touched on AJAX in my response, in the event that it was actually an AJAX issue he was dealing with in his real world example, but was just using setTimeout for a stripped down way to reproduce the issue. There are absolutely no grounds for *assuming* that that is the case, but you'll notice in my answer, I don't make that assumption, and I don't focus on AJAX.

Comment: Thanks David. I was looking in the wrong place and used a bad example - thanks for clearing that up and expanding my javascript knowledge.

Comment: Don't get mr wrong your solution is very elogant and spot on, it's just sometimes Ajax seems to confused with boring old JavaScript

Comment: @DavidHedlund Is your solution valid for 2 functions alone? how do I make sure 3rd function is called after second? Is it like longfunctionfirst(shortfunctionsecond(thirdFunction));

Comment: @SukanyaPai: No, this answer was written 10 years ago to explain a specific pattern of passing callbacks. In your code, `shortfunctionsecond` would be called first, as you're calling it, and not just passing it as a parameter. The result of `shortfunctionsecond(thirdFunction)` will be passed to `longfunctionfirst`. An up to date answer that handles the complexity you introduce would be to use [Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)

Answer (score 38):

I am back to this questions after all this time because it took me that long to find what I think is a clean solution :
The only way to force a javascript sequential execution that I know of is to use promises.
There are exhaustive explications of promises at : [Promises/A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) and [Promises/A+](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/)

The only library implementing promises I know is jquery so here is how I would solve the question using jquery promises :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction()
    {
        promise = longfunctionfirst().then(shortfunctionsecond);
    }
    function longfunctionfirst()
    {
        d = new $.Deferred();
        setTimeout('alert("first function finished");d.resolve()',3000);
        return d.promise()
    }
    function shortfunctionsecond()
    {
        d = new $.Deferred();
        setTimeout('alert("second function finished");d.resolve()',200);
        return d.promise()
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:myfunction();return false;">Call my function</a>
</body>
</html>
```

By implementing a promise and chaining the functions with .then() you ensure that the second function will be executed only after the first one has executed
It is the command d.resolve() in longfunctionfirst() that give the signal to start the next function.

Technically the shortfunctionsecond() does not need to create a deferred and return a promise, but I fell in love with promises and tend to implement everything with promises, sorry.

Comment: Promises actually are part of the current (2015) ECMAscript draft: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-promise-objects

Comment: People still reading this old answer ? Thanks, yes Javascript moves on, just waiting for the 2015 draft to catch up with all the browsers out there :-)

Comment: Hi All, I am always surprised that this old tread still attract attention. Yes you are right, now ES6 and an increasing number of frameworks implement promises. This is old stuff, but it drove me up the wall 5 years ago and was the hardest lesson I ever learned in computing. Simply put I was stuck in a Von Newmann sequential understanding of computing and could not grasp the beauty of event driven development embraced by Javascript.

Answer (score 13):

I am an old hand at programming and came back recently to my old passion and am struggling to fit in this Object oriented, event driven bright new world and while i see the advantages of the non sequential behavior of Javascript there are time where it really get in the way of simplicity and reusability.
A simple example I have worked on was to take a photo (Mobile phone programmed in javascript, HTML, phonegap, ...), resize it and upload it on a web site.
The ideal sequence is :

1. Take a photo
2. Load the photo in an img element
3. Resize the picture (Using Pixastic)
4. Upload it to a web site
5. Inform the user on success failure

All this would be a very simple sequential program if we would have each step returning control to the next one when it is finished, but in reality :

1. Take a photo is async, so the program attempt to load it in the img element before it exist
2. Load the photo is async so the resize picture start before the img is fully loaded
3. Resize is async so Upload to the web site start before the Picture is completely resized
4. Upload to the web site is asyn so the program continue before the photo is completely uploaded.

And btw 4 of the 5 steps involve callback functions.

My solution thus is to nest each step in the previous one and use .onload and other similar stratagems, It look something like this :

```
takeAPhoto(takeaphotocallback(photo) {
  photo.onload = function () {
    resizePhoto(photo, resizePhotoCallback(photo) {
      uploadPhoto(photo, uploadPhotoCallback(status) {
        informUserOnOutcome();
      });
    }); 
  };
  loadPhoto(photo);
});
```

(I hope I did not make too many mistakes bringing the code to it's essential the real thing is just too distracting)

This is I believe a perfect example where async is no good and sync is good, because contrary to Ui event handling we must have each step finish before the next is executed, but the code is a Russian doll construction, it is confusing and unreadable, the code reusability is difficult to achieve because of all the nesting it is simply difficult to bring to the inner function all the parameters needed without passing them to each container in turn or using evil global variables, and I would have loved that the result of all this code would give me a return code, but the first container will be finished well before the return code will be available.

Now to go back to Tom initial question, what would be the smart, easy to read, easy to reuse solution to what would have been a very simple program 15 years ago using let say C and a dumb electronic board ?

The requirement is in fact so simple that I have the impression that I must be missing a fundamental understanding of Javsascript and modern programming, Surely technology is meant to fuel productivity right  ?.

Thanks for your patience

Raymond the Dinosaur ;-)

Comment: I have experienced the same difficulties with phonegap. I have a code full of nested callback functions, which is hard to read. At some point I was wishing I had implemented the app natively. I was working on an audio recorder and synchronizing recorded data with the server. I tried to simplify my code with requirejs and backbone. This helped a little to pull things apart and organizing the code in modules, but I still need to nest callbacks...

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the first function does actually complete before the second function is started. setTimeout does not hold execution of the function until the timeout is reached, it will simply start a timer in the background and execute your alert statement after the specified time.

There is no native way of doing a "sleep" in JavaScript. You could write a loop that checks for the time, but that will put a lot of strain on the client. You could also do the Synchronous AJAX call, as emacsian described, but that will put extra load on your server. Your best bet is really to avoid this, which should be simple enough for most cases once you understand how setTimeout works.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't insist on using pure Javascript, you can build a sequential code in [Livescript](http://livescript.net) and it **looks pretty good**. You might want to take a look at [this example](https://github.com/ceremcem/livescript-examples/blob/86e33e1ba989cbd935e76dd61c222a802dd203b3/events-example.ls):

```
# application
do
    i = 3
    console.log td!, "start"
    <- :lo(op) ->
        console.log td!, "hi #{i}"
        i--
        <- wait-for \something
        if i is 0
            return op! # break
        lo(op)
    <- sleep 1500ms
    <- :lo(op) ->
        console.log td!, "hello #{i}"
        i++
        if i is 3
            return op! # break
        <- sleep 1000ms
        lo(op)
    <- sleep 0
    console.log td!, "heyy"

do
    a = 8
    <- :lo(op) ->
        console.log td!, "this runs in parallel!", a
        a--
        go \something
        if a is 0
            return op! # break
        <- sleep 500ms
        lo(op)
```

Output:

```
0ms : start
2ms : hi 3
3ms : this runs in parallel! 8
3ms : hi 2
505ms : this runs in parallel! 7
505ms : hi 1
1007ms : this runs in parallel! 6
1508ms : this runs in parallel! 5
2009ms : this runs in parallel! 4
2509ms : hello 0
2509ms : this runs in parallel! 3
3010ms : this runs in parallel! 2
3509ms : hello 1
3510ms : this runs in parallel! 1
4511ms : hello 2
4511ms : heyy
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, this is my solution:

```js
var functionsToCall = new Array();

function f1() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/some/url",
        success: function(data) {
            doSomethingWith(data);
            //When done, call the next function..
            callAFunction("parameter");
        }
    });
}

function f2() {
    /*...*/
    callAFunction("parameter2");
}
function f3() {
    /*...*/
    callAFunction("parameter3");
}
function f4() {
    /*...*/
    callAFunction("parameter4");
}
function f5() {
    /*...*/
    callAFunction("parameter5");
}
function f6() {
    /*...*/
    callAFunction("parameter6");
}
function f7() {
    /*...*/
    callAFunction("parameter7");
}
function f8() {
    /*...*/
    callAFunction("parameter8");
}
function f9() {
    /*...*/
    callAFunction("parameter9");
}
    
function callAllFunctionsSy(params) {
 functionsToCall.push(f1);
 functionsToCall.push(f2);
 functionsToCall.push(f3);
 functionsToCall.push(f4);
 functionsToCall.push(f5);
 functionsToCall.push(f6);
 functionsToCall.push(f7);
 functionsToCall.push(f8);
 functionsToCall.push(f9);
 functionsToCall.reverse();
 callAFunction(params);
}

function callAFunction(params) {
 if (functionsToCall.length > 0) {
  var f=functionsToCall.pop();
  f(params);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, there is no way, to make the code wait. I've had this problem and the way I did it was do a synchronous SJAX call to the server, and the server actually executes sleep or does some activity before returning and the whole time, the js waits.

Eg of Sync AJAX: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Snippets:_Synchronous_AJAX

Comment: SJAX is typically a sign of bad design and I would encourage novices to avoid it until they understand its implications.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the callback way and could not get this to work, what you have to understand is that values are still atomic even though execution is not. For example:

`alert('1');` <--- these two functions will be executed at the same time

`alert('2');` <--- these two functions will be executed at the same time

but doing like this will force us to know the order of execution:

```
loop=2;
total=0;
for(i=0;i<loop;i++) {
           total+=1;
           if(total == loop)
                      alert('2');
           else
                      alert('1');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at this is to daisy chain from one function to another.
Have an array of functions that is global to all your called functions, say:

```
arrf: [ f_final
       ,f
       ,another_f
       ,f_again ],
```

Then setup an array of integers to the particular 'f''s you want to run, e.g

```
var runorder = [1,3,2,0];
```

Then call an initial function with 'runorder' as a parameter, e.g.
    f_start(runorder);

Then at the end of each function, just pop the index to the next 'f' to execute off the runorder array and execute it, still passing 'runorder' as a parameter but with the array reduced by one.

```
var nextf = runorder.shift();
arrf[nextf].call(runorder);
```

Obviously this terminates in a function, say at index 0, that does not chain onto another function.
This is completely deterministic, avoiding 'timers'.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in a string, iterate, eval, setTimeout and recursion to continue with the remaining lines. No doubt I'll refine this or just throw it out if it doesn't hit the mark. My intention is to use it to simulate really, really basic user testing.

The recursion and setTimeout make it sequential.

Thoughts?

```
var line_pos = 0;
var string =`
    console.log('123');
    console.log('line pos is '+ line_pos);
SLEEP
    console.log('waited');
    console.log('line pos is '+ line_pos);
SLEEP
SLEEP
    console.log('Did i finish?');
`;

var lines = string.split("\n");
var r = function(line_pos){
    for (i = p; i < lines.length; i++) { 
        if(lines[i] == 'SLEEP'){
            setTimeout(function(){r(line_pos+1)},1500);
            return;
        }
        eval (lines[line_pos]);
    }
    console.log('COMPLETED READING LINES');
    return;
}
console.log('STARTED READING LINES');
r.call(this,line_pos);
```

OUTPUT

```
STARTED READING LINES
123
124
1 p is 0
undefined
waited
p is 5
125
Did i finish?
COMPLETED READING LINES
```