# In javascript, execute a function when the first function is ready

Tags: javascript, chaining, onready

Is there any way, in javascript, to call on a other function when the first function is "ready"

something like this:

```
ridiculousTimeConsumingFunction().onReady( newFunction() );
```

To illustrate my example you can take a look her:
http://web.cinaird.se/pdf/test.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859185/how-to-force-sequential-javascript-execution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>ridiculousTimeConsumingFunction();
    newFunction();</strike>

Will execute `newFunction()` after `ridiculousTimeConsumingFunction()` has finished.

You could also do something like `ridiculousTimeConsumingFunction(newFunction);`, and have ridiculousTimeConsumingFunction defined as follows:

```
function ridiculousTimeConsumingFunction(callback) {
   for (var i=0;i<1000000000;i++) {

   };

   callback();
}
```

Which would have the same effect.

Infact, scrap all that, because it's an asynchronous event, not a time consuming function... You'll have to use a callback:

```
function longFunction (callback) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".theDiv").css('height', 200 );
    callback();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Then call it as follows:

```
longFunction(function () {
      $("#info").html(info);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept of "ready" is not generally defined for asynchronous functions like your example. Usually this kind of thing is done through callbacks:

```
function asyncFunc(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    doSomething();
    callback();
  }, 1000);
}

asyncFunc(function() {alert('Done!');}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by **ready** when DOM is ready, there is no such event, however you can use **[jQuery's](http://jquery.org)** `ready` handler to fire your function when DOM becomes ready.

With Javascript you could fire your function in `load` event too like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  // your function code here
};
```

Or

```
window.onload = somefunction;
```

Comment: @M28: You are right, typed it in a sort of habit, fixed anyways. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your sample, the "ridiculousTimeConsumingFunction" function doesn't actually take all that long to execute: it just scheduled *another* function to run 1 second in the future.

If you want to do something like this, I would suggest you check out [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)'s effects API. It allows you to "chain" animations together one after the other and should achieve the effect you're after.