# BootStrap alert behaving strange

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-dialog

I have very strange problem with twitter bootstrap alert box. Here is the sample I was trying to execute

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-dialog.css">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
function callMe(){
    test();
    BootstrapDialog.alert('Bye');
}
    function test(){
          BootstrapDialog.alert('hello');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" name="button"  value="button" onclick="callMe()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Result should be : hello ----> Bye

Result coming as : Bye ----> hello

If I comment one Bootstrap alert box then also same result(No point of dilog box overlapping).

```
function callMe(){
    test();
}
    function test(){
    alert('inside test');
          BootstrapDialog.alert('hello');
          alert('outside test');
    }
</script>
```

Result coming as : inside test--->outside test--->hello
Result should be : inside test--->hello--->outside test

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because the calls are asynchronous. The time taken by the control to return back from `test()` is more than the `BootstrapDialog.alert('Bye');`

If you put a timeinterval of say 1 sec. like:
`setInterval(BootstrapDialog.alert('Bye'), 1000);` Or use a callback method
**jQuery Callback Functions**.

It is a great chance to start using **"jQuery Deferred"**.

This stackoverflow link [sequencing function calls in javascript - are callbacks the only way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274114/sequencing-function-calls-in-javascript-are-callbacks-the-only-way)
might help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `hello` dialog is behind the other.
You first made a call to create the `hello` dialog and after you create the `bye` dialog on the top of the first, that is, the second dialog overwritten the first.

Comment: its not correct, if I exectue as below function callMe(){
 test();
 //BootstrapDialog.alert('VBye');
}
 function test(){
 alert('inside test');
          BootstrapDialog.alert('hello');
          alert('outside test');
    }
</script>   ...Result is -->inside test---outside test--->hello