# Stop async execution of code js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

After login I have function which gets control.

```
function formLoginSubmit() {
    if (typeof window.formLoginSubmit_custom != 'undefined') {
        window.formLoginSubmit_custom();
    }
    location.href = '/';
}
```

And in function `formLoginSubmit_custom()` I have to do some operations with opening Iframes.
The problem is that:

1. I can't modify `formLoginSubmit` (don't ask it's just a task I have to do)
2. Before I've done all operations with my iframes document starts redirecting
   because of this:  `location.href = '/';`

So how can I stop executing code asyncronously 
And let my `formLoginSubmit_custom()` function finish all the operations before changing 
`location.href`

What are my options?

Comment: If you can't modify `formLoginSubmit_custom` and it is performing async operation, you are in trouble... The only thing you can do is schedule the location change with setTimeout and hope formLoginSubmit_custom has complete.
Otherwise, change `formLoginSubmit_custom` to accept a callback and to call it when async operation complete. In the callback body, you'll change the location

Comment: This article may help you [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859185/how-to-force-sequential-javascript-execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. You would need to change formLoginSubmit to achieve that.

You could drop a cookie "do some work", and when page is reloaded, if you can execute some code - if you find a "do some work" cookie - you could execute that custom() logic in there. But that might not be useful for you depending on what you're trying to achieve.